# Cannot right-click wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8

I am trying to setup a wireless connection in Windows 8. I need to be able to access the connection settings to configure the connection correctly, but unless you connect to the network, it won't let me access that menu. Is there any way for me to get to that menu without connecting first?

Note: The menu that I want to get to is the same menu that appears in windows 7 under

"Network and Sharing Center -> Manage wireless networks -> Add -> Manually create a network profile"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to control panel (Windows Key + X, then P), go to Network and Internet, Network and Sharing center, click Set Up a New Connection, and select Manually Connect to a wireless network.